# HTTP question, about X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network and Accept-Encoding

Tags: http, encoding

May I ask somebody who explain to me what is the difference between
X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip and Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br?
What should I use if I would reach better performance?